# Matlab compiled to. NET - what about thread safety?

Tags: c#, multithreading, matlab, matlab-deployment

If I to call matlab function compiled by Builder NE in multi-threaded near real-time application, how should. I approach thread safety issue? Shall I create single instance of matlab object and serialize access in c# or shall I instantiate one object for each thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a single instance, the MCR will serialize access for you. One object per thread might be too much overhead.

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-ELVN0M/index.html?product=CO&solution=1-ELVN0M

*Note - MCR is the MATLAB runtime, you could think of it as a scaled down MATLAB session running in the backgroun.

Comment: I found in the doc that there will be created one instance of MCR for each Matlab object instance in the .NET app.. So yes you are right it will be serialised in sence. So the real answer - the Matlab objects somewhat thread-safe unless Matlab developer breaks this (using global vars etc - all described in the Builder pdf).